# Personalized/random URLs in Python/Django

Tags: python, html, django, url, random

I'm a Python beginner (and English language beginner too, by the way).
I just created a simple form in Python/Django that creates, edit and remove items.
I have HTML links that refers to my URLs like:

FILE.HTML:

```
<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Edit" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/edit/{{ object.id }}/'">
```

URLS.PY:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.editobj'),
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
def editobj(request, id):
```

But of course, there's a problem, I wouldn't like people go direct on URL (only if the button was clicked) because somebody could just type on URL: /removeobj/1 and remove the object ID=1. What I would like to do is create differente URLs, maybe random, so the user would never guess what is the URL that the button will open, and of course, that it does work with the ID argument, so when it's goind to edit/remove, opens the right object.
I'm Hoping I was clear on my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Don't rely on URL obfuscation for security. Find some way to keep track of who can edit or remove specific objects and validate that before allowing any data modification (and maybe display, depending on your situation).

Comment: Thank you. My intend is to develop a login function, so this could be controlled by users too, but I would also like to do an URL obfuscation, just to increment security.

Comment: If there's a reason to worry about obscuring the IDs, I would probably do something like append the ID to a fixed length string of random values (eg `os.urandom(16).encode('hex')` gives you 32 random hex digits), make sure that field has `db_indexed=True`, and use that in place of ID. Appending the ID guarantees that the values are unique even if you get the same random string. But that's overkill for almost all situations if you have an owner/permissions system, and probably not sufficient if your login system is breakable.

Answer (score 1):

Generating random URL's would be highly inefficient, not to mention unnecessarily difficult to implement. The common way to do what you are asking is to POST to a URL. I think you should do a little more reading on Django POSTing, as it will help you get a better understanding of what it does. In any case, here is an example of using this:

urls.py

```
url(r'^delete/$', 'app.views.delete_object', name="delete_obj"),
```

views.py

```
def delete_object(request):
""" Get the ID of an object via POST, then delete it. """
    if request.method == 'POST'  # This makes sure the request is a POST
        obj_id = request.POST['obj_id']
        obj = MODELNAME.objects.get(id=obj_id)  # Use your model name here

        # You can use if conditions here to make sure the object you just
        # retrieved is allowed to be deleted by this user, or in general.

        obj.delete()

        messages.success(request, 'Object successfully deleted!')
    return redirect(reverse('index'))  # Make sure you use a name that exists
```

.html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_obj' %}">
    {% CSRF_TOKEN %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ obj.id }}" name="obj_id" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

You can use more logic in the views.py to make sure that the object is allowed to be deletable, but for the most part, the code I wrote should give you somewhat of an understanding of the way to create a POST -> Delete Object workflow. Feel free to ask questions in the comment section below my answer.

Comment: IMO that doesn't really address the OP's question about obscuring the IDs. It's not significantly harder to check the source for the page, find the field containing the ID, and create a POST using a new ID than it is just to change the URL. So if there's any solid reason to worry about showing the ID this is just as vulnerable as the original version.

Comment: 100% Agree with you, but the OP's question lacked insight on the ability for server-side validation. I tried to lay out the foundation as best I could considering the lack of information I was provided, so now he can validate with the security of a CSRF token, as well as inside `delete_object()`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see to do a "random" url would be to add a UUIDField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield or https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield for Django <1.8) with a default to your model.

Your url can then become

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<uuid>[\da-f-]+)', 'app.views.delete_object', name='delete_obj')
```

uuid's are virtually impossible to guess.

Now if you don't add extra security to check that the user **has the right** to delete the object, anyone could still run a robot that would go through every single possible uuid and flush your database.

And if it is just a matter of not "guessing" @Hybrid's solution is probably a better starting point.